# Como abrir um arquivo local com o Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Usando o Xamarin com o Visual Studio e C#, fiz uma aplicação Android e estou criando um player usando o `VideoView`.

Gostaria de saber como acessar a pasta do celular que contém o vídeo.

Por exemplo:
`"/storage/pasta/video.mp4"`.

Sei que é algo com o `.SetVideoPath` do `VideoView`, mas não entendi como.

Comment: Tente ver aqui na própria documentação do Xamarin. Vai te ajudar bastante: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/browse_files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ronaldo, não entendi se é bem isso que você quer, mas quando eu tenho que acessar determinada pasta eu utilizo o seguinte código:

```
var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonVideos);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
```

Agora com o filePath eu já tenho o caminho a ser acessado (no caso da pasta padrão de videos).

Veja se o link [Trabalhando com arquivos](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/) te  ajuda.